# Next-auth logIn() is stuck on /api/auth/providers while using Credentials provider

Tags: javascript, next.js, frontend, next-auth

Next-auth logIn() is stuck endlessly on /api/auth/providers as can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kMRa.png).

`async authorize(credentials)` part doesn't seem to be executed at all, as none of the `console.log` seem to be working

**/pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js**

```
import Providers from 'next-auth/providers';
import connectDB from '../../../lib/connectDB';
import User from '../../../models/User';

export default NextAuth({
    //Configure JWT
    session: {
        jwt: true,
    },
    //Specify Provider
    providers: [
        Providers.Credentials({
            async authorize(credentials) {
                console.log('====THIS MESSAGE IS NOT SHOWN ON CONSOLE====')
                connectDB();
                const user = await User.findOne({
                    email: credentials.email,
                });

                console.log(user);

                if (user & (await user.matchPassword(credentials.passowrd))) {
                    client.close();
                    return { email: user.email };
                }
                client.close();
                return null;
            },
        }),
    ],
});
```

**Client Side**

```
  const onLogin = async (values) => {
        const status = await signIn('credentials', {
            redirect: false,
            email: values.email,
            password: values.password,
        });
        console.log('Login Status: ', status);
        // This is not logged as well, due to /api/auth/providers being stuck
  }
```

Comment: Discussion on GitHub: https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/discussions/2588

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that yuo're not defining the fields in the credentials provider setup in `[...nextauth].js` ?

https://next-auth.js.org/v3/configuration/providers#how-to-2

[image]

Comment: The problem somehow is related to the version of Yarn I use, which is v3.

Comment: Yeah I saw the next-auth discussion content.. But have you tried the above ^^ ?